# Any modification to API Gateway's Integration Response Mapping Templates causes 500 error

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I'm in Amazon's API Gateway, and any change to the Mapping Templates section of the Integration Response breaks the Resource/Method (causes the Test to return an error) and cannot be fixed (you must delete the Resource/Method and create a new one).

- I create a new Resource, then create a new Method (POST) under that.
- I map this to a simple Lambda function (it doesn't require any parameters and only returns/logs 'hi').
- I test this, and it succeeds.
- I go into Integration Response, and I change the Mapping Templates ... I change `application/json` to `application/xml` and I change 'Output passthrough' to 'Mapping template'.

I enter this as the template:

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Message>
        <Body>
            $inputRoot
        </Body>
    </Message>
</Response>
```

- I save that by clicking the checkbox and by clicking the Save button.
- I go back to test it

This is the result:

```
{
  "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

This is the content of the Logs output (I replaced potentially sensitive information with [explanation here] since I'm not sure what's sensitive or not):

```
Execution log for request test-request
Sun Dec 06 17:33:50 UTC 2015 : Starting execution for request: test-invoke-request
Sun Dec 06 17:33:50 UTC 2015 : API Key: test-invoke-api-key
Sun Dec 06 17:33:50 UTC 2015 : Method request path: {}
Sun Dec 06 17:33:50 UTC 2015 : Method request query string: {}
Sun Dec 06 17:33:50 UTC 2015 : Method request headers: {}
Sun Dec 06 17:33:50 UTC 2015 : Method request body before transformations: null
Sun Dec 06 17:33:50 UTC 2015 : Endpoint request URI: [lambda uri here]
Sun Dec 06 17:33:50 UTC 2015 : Endpoint request headers: {Authorization=[lots of * here], X-Amz-Date=20151206T173350Z, X-Amz-Source-Arn=[arn here], Accept=application/json, User-Agent=AmazonAPIGateway_[string here], Host=lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com}
Sun Dec 06 17:33:50 UTC 2015 : Endpoint request body after transformations: 
Sun Dec 06 17:33:50 UTC 2015 : Endpoint response body before transformations: "hi"
Sun Dec 06 17:33:50 UTC 2015 : Endpoint response headers: {x-amzn-Remapped-Content-Length=0, x-amzn-RequestId=[data here], Connection=keep-alive, Content-Length=12, Date=Sun, 06 Dec 2015 17:33:50 GMT, Content-Type=application/json}
Sun Dec 06 17:33:50 UTC 2015 : Execution failed due to configuration error: No match for output mapping and no default output mapping configured
Sun Dec 06 17:33:50 UTC 2015 : Method completed with status: 500
```

- I also tried going into Method Response, and changing the Content Type for Response Models for 200 from `application/json` to `application/xml` ... That produced the same error.
- I also tried, at this point, to revert my changes ... Method Response back to `application/json` & Integration Response back to `application/json` and 'Output passthrough' ... That produced the same error - it's like this API Resource/Method is now permanently broken.

I also tested another new Resource, changing only the Content Type for Response Models for 200 in Method Response from 'application/json' to 'application/xml' ... This resulted in a successful test.

I also tried a more minor change to the Mapping Templates in Integration Response ... Rather than a full switch from 'Output passthrough' to 'Mapping Template', I just changed the content type from `application/json` to `application/xml` ... This resulted in the same error.

So it seems like the root cause is changing from Output Passthrough to Mapping Template ... Once that change is made, the test will fail & you will not be able to return it to a passing state - you must delete the Resource/Method entirely & start a new one.

Also, to be clear, there are no deploys throughout any of this process - I'm strictly working in the AWS console itself, using their 'Test' link in the web interface.

Anyone know what's going on here?
I'm also trying to get an answer in their [Discussion Forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=221197), but those threads usually aren't nearly as active as here...

**Added Note**
I do have a functional deploy running, which uses this mapping template. That deploy is from `18:35 12-05-2015`, so it's possible that this is a new error/change in the Amazon API Gateway...

Comment: I am also facing this problem. I don't have an answer yet, but I thought I would add that saving the mapping template using the check mark does seem to save it. You don't have to click the big "Save" button, which is what seems to break it for me. You can execute the test, and the mapping function will execute, but it just wont be visible anywhere in the UI. Next time you go back to edit it, it will be set back to "Output Passthrough", even though the mapping template is still in effect. Frustrating. Basically, don't ever click the big Save button.

Comment: Not clicking the big Save button might help for in-console tests, but I just tested a deploy without clicking the Save button & I got the same error response (so your suggestion doesn't seem to apply to deploys, unfortunately).

Comment: Interesting - I'll experiment some more with deploys, but I did just discover that completely refreshing the main API page and then going back into the Integration Response page causes the Mapping Template to refresh properly, showing whatever changes you made last. If you don't refresh the page and navigate around the API console normally, it doesn't ever seem to update.

Comment: So FWIW, I just did a deploy, with a mapping template inside of the integration response. Seemed to work without the internal server error

Comment: Same here. I'm not doing anything any differently, but now Mapping Templates are working as long as I avoid that big Save button.

Answer (score 2):

This must have been a temporary issue with API Gateway, because the issue is gone now.

There's **one caveat**:

**NEVER** click the big Save button on the Integration Response page. That seems to cause issues, at least as of today (2015-12-05).

Comment: I have noticed that if I add a mapping template to one method and then navigate to another and back it will appear like it's not there.  Or if I add a query parameter or header mapping.  I've found that if I refresh the browser I'll see the modification so I've changed my habits to always do a browser refresh after apply a modification.

Answer (score 1):

I spoke with amazon's support staff and its a known issue. As long as you don't press the Save button you should be fine but once you do there is no going back.

Just press the checkbox thing when making changes to the template and refresh the page. That seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue with APIs when saving the default integration response mapping. The bug caused requests to your API methods that were saved incorrectly to return a 500 error, the CloudWatch logs should say "Execution failed due to configuration error: No match for output mapping and no default output mapping configured".

The issue is now resolved. If you are experiencing this, please re-deploy your API configuration.

For more information, please refer to this AWS forums entry: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=221197&tstart=0

Regards,
Jurgen

Answer (score 0):

The issue is now resolved. It's now safe to save the default integration response. If your deployed APIs are having issues, a redeploy should resolve the problem. Thanks for your patience.

Ryan